# The server tag is not well formed - hyperlink databound

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a formatting issue with my hyperlink, it works OK with the text part along so I know it's an issue with the JavaScript but don't know what the problem is.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCustType" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>'
            NavigateUrl="javascript:sendval('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>');">
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the asp:hyperlink with a normal html tag link:

```
<a href="javascript:sendval('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>');">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>'</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

'The problem is, you have closed the string in the NavigateUrl Property. You should use `'` or `\"` inside of inline code to not end the string.
So you should try this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCustType" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>'
            NavigateUrl="javascript:sendval('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, \'CustType\') %>');">
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypCustType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:sendval(\"" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") + "\");" %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```